# setting only the last value of the query to 1

Tags: mysql, insert, union

I wrote a long query for my rest api and it should only set the last value which is `wins` to 1.

I have been trying but I keep on getting a syntax error. Is there even a way to set only one value in such a query to 1?

thanks in advance

```
"INSERT INTO danceoffs (id, name, powermove,avatar,wins)
VALUES (,,,,1) SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, name ,powermove,avatar FROM  Robots_1 
UNION SELECT  id, name ,powermove FROM  Robots_2) AS U WHERE name = ? "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `1` as the value for the column `wins` but both unioned queries must return the same number of columns, so if there is no column `avatar` in `Robots_2` you can use `null`:

```
INSERT INTO danceoffs (id, name, powermove, avatar, wins)
SELECT U.*, 1 
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, powermove, avatar FROM  Robots_1 
  UNION 
  SELECT  id, name, powermove, null FROM  Robots_2
) AS U 
WHERE U.name = ?
```